# Why don't you have to handle possible exceptions thrown by classes in the `java.lang` package?

Tags: java, throws

So, in the documentation for example: [`java.lang.Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-), I noticed that the code header is:

```
public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException
```

However, when one has a statement something like `int i = Integer.parseInt(someString);` the code compiles fine without a `try-catch` block.

Now, on the other hand, if I write a method with the header:

```
public void connectTo(String ip) throws java.net.HostNotFoundException
```

and make a call to it without surrounding the call with a proper `try-catch` block, the compiler just won't have it. I'm not suggesting that I (or anyone) would want to surround every single `Integer.parseInt` call (and others) with a `try-catch` block, but I sure am curious as to why the compiler allows it.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on checked and unchecked exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `NumberFormatException` subclasses [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html), which in turn subclasses [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html).

Subclasses of `RuntimeException`, unlike those of `Exception`, do not need to be explicitly caught (although they can be).

From the `RuntimeException` javadoc page:

> RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions. Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Because those exceptions are [unchecked](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

From the attached link:

> Because the Java programming language does not require methods to
>   catch or to specify unchecked exceptions (RuntimeException, Error, and
>   their subclasses), programmers may be tempted to write code that
>   throws only unchecked exceptions or to make all their exception
>   subclasses inherit from RuntimeException. Both of these shortcuts
>   allow programmers to write code without bothering with compiler errors
>   and without bothering to specify or to catch any exceptions. Although
>   this may seem convenient to the programmer, it sidesteps the intent of
>   the catch or specify requirement and can cause problems for others
>   using your classes.